# How to get two dates difference in hours?

Tags: sql, oracle, datediff

I'm trying to add the total hours clocked by an employee I can get the hours worked for each job, but can't add them together.

I'm using the following code to get the far.

```
SELECT 
      TO_DATE(TRIP.RETURN_DATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY')
      - TO_DATE(TRIP.DEPARTURE_DATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY') AS duration,
      TRIP.EMPLOYEE_NO AS employee
 FROM EMPLOYEE, TRIP;
```

And it returns result in the following format:

```
 DURATION | EMPLOYEE 
---------------------
    5     | 0037759    
    8     | 0037759    
    2     | 0037759    
    3     | 0037759    
    3     | 0037759
```

How to add the duration for each employee?

Comment: look up how `group by` works

Comment: What is the data type of trip.return_date and trip.departure_date?

Comment: `TO_DATE(TRIP.RETURN_DATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY')` Why do you apply **TO_DATE** on a **DATE**? What is the **datatype** of `RETURN_DATE`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your table structures so I am making some assumptions here. You are ALSO missing a JOIN to link employee and trip together.

```
SELECT SUM(TO_DATE(TRIP.RETURN_DATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY') - TO_DATE(TRIP.DEPARTURE_DATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY')) duration, 
TRIP.EMPLOYEE_NO AS employee
FROM employee JOIN trip on trip.employee_no = employee.employee_no

GROUP BY  employee.employee_no
```

Comment: Remember to mulitpy by 24.

Comment: Thanks! this was really helpful!